# React select check on key down event whether menu is open or closed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-select

I am using **react-select** in my project for the select elements.

I wonder if there is a way to check on keydown event in the select (can be both the select input or on the menu) if the menu is open or closed.

I am using react select version ^2.4.2, and have to support explorer.

P.S: for whoever is not familiar with the react-select library: it doesnt create typical HTML 'select' and 'option' elements, but rather a text input and on each click (or some dedicated keydown events (accessibility)) on the input/menu - it toggles a div with the options.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish? Not getting much clarity from the question.

Answer (score 4):

found the answer for it - I am using the built in onMenuClose and onMenuOpen props to toggle a custom attribute (e.g. 'is-open') value between true/false on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
selectRef.current.state.focusedOptionId
```

selectRef is your react-select ref
state.focusedOptionId is null is menu closed
state.focusedOptionId has value is menu open

you can detect it on keydown event, but i didnot try when react-select has no options